# ¿Cómo se genera un PDF por registro en Django usando .get?

Tags: python, django

tengo una pregunta, sucede que estoy tratando de generar un PDF cuando se da click a un botón.
Solo que no sé porque si utilizo  `carros=Carro.objects.all()`  sirve, me despliega toda la información muy bien; pero cuando utilizo esto: `carros=Carro.objects.get(id=id)` , me aparece un error:

**Carro matching query does not exist.**
[image: error]

Lo que necesito es generar el PDF por registro, no quiero un PDF de todos los registros, sólo el que se necesita consultar.

> model

```
class Carro(models.Model):
    placas=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    tipo=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    marca=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    modelo=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    año=models.IntegerField()
    vin=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    color=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    motor=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    agente_seguros=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    compañia_seguros=models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    no_politica=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    cliente= models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True)
    fotosCarro=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    garantia=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    fecha_registros = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, null=True,blank=True)
```

> url

```
path('pdf/<int:id>', views.estimatePdf, name='estimate-pdf'),
```

> views

```
def estimatePdf(request,id):
    buf=io.BytesIO()
    c=canvas.Canvas(buf,pagesize=letter,bottomup=0)
    textob=c.beginText()
    textob.setTextOrigin(inch,inch)
    textob.setFont("Helvetica",14)

    carros=Carro.objects.get(id=id)

    lines=[]

    for carro in carros:
        lines.append(carro.placas)
        lines.append(carro.tipo)
        lines.append(carro.marca)
        lines.append("")

    for line in lines:
        textob.textLine(line)

    c.drawText(textob)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    buf.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename='estimate.pdf')
```

> html

```
<button class="btn btn-light btn-sm w-xs"><a href="{% url 'Presupuestos:estimate-pdf' presupuesto.id%}">PDF </a><i class="uil uil-download-alt ms-2"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

deberias poner el modelo de Carro para estar más claro, pero suponiendo que el id lo tengas como llave primaria(pk), es tan solo poner

```
carros=Carro.objects.get(pk=id)
```

Otra cosa, el metodo get solo devuelve una instancia (ademas estas bunscando por el id, por lo que hay una sola instancia), pero debajo de la consulta estas recoriendolo como si fuera una lista. De no funcionarte sube el modelo carro y toda el mensaje de error para esclarecer un poco mas la situación.

Comment: listo, ya subí el modelo y el error. No no me funcionó colocando pk=id :(